# Insert Forename Surname (Joe Bloggs) into two separate columns

Tags: php

I have a string that looks like:

```
$string = 'Joe Bloggs';
```

and in my database, i have 2 columns, `forename` and `surname`

how can i insert this string into the two separate columns

so `Joe` inserts into `forename` and `Bloggs` inserts into `surname`

Also, if the string looks like

`$string = 'John B. Doe';` or

```
$string = 'John B Doe';
```

I would want to insert

`John B` or `John B.` into `forename` and `Doe` into `surname`

So everything in the string apart from the last word will insert into `forename` and then the last word will insert into `surname`

Comment: *"Good luck with that."* — Jon B. van Westerhuisen, friends with Rodolfo Alfonso Raffaello Piero Filiberto Guglielmi di Valentina d’Antoguella ;-)

Comment: You should probably have a read of [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: im never going to have names like that

Comment: ...said every programmer, ever. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) combined with [array_pop](https://www.php.net/array_pop) and implode:

```
$array = explode(" ",$string);
$surname = array_pop($array);
$forename = implode(" ",$array);
```

Comment: tried your code, but your $forename is the surname and your $surname is the forename

Answer (score 0):

**Try it simple using exploding a string with space**

```
$string = 'Joe Bloggs';
$arr = explode(" ",$string);
echo $arr[0]; // this your forename
echo $arr[1]; // this your surname
```